# Unexpected behavior Log4NetExtension in combination with registered IEnumerable<T> in Unity container

Tags: c#, unity-container

I am using **log4net** as logging framework and **Unity** as my IoC container. Next, I have installed the **Unity.log4net** nuget package. I run into an issue with the logger name when I start using named registrations. I use named registrations to enable constructor injection of an IEnumerable of T.

The code below is a very simple program which shows my problem.

```
using Container.Activities;
using log4net;
using Unity;
using Unity.log4net;

[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]

namespace Container
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
            container.AddNewExtension<Log4NetExtension>();

            container.RegisterType<IActivity, ActivityA>(nameof(ActivityA));
            container.RegisterType<IActivity, ActivityB>(nameof(ActivityB));
            container.RegisterType<IActivityExecutor, ActivityExecutor>();

            var logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Test application");
            logger.Info("Application started.");

            container.Resolve<IActivityExecutor>().Execute();

            logger.Info("Application stopped.");
        }
    }
}
```

I create an Activity interface and will have multiple implementations of this interface.

```
namespace Container.Activities
{
    public interface IActivity
    {
        void Execute();
    }
}
```

In this example I have just two implementations, Activity A and B. Both implementations require an log4net.ILog implementation to be injected in the constructor.

```
using log4net;

namespace Container.Activities
{
    public class ActivityA : IActivity
    {
        private readonly ILog _logger;

        public ActivityA(ILog logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void Execute()
        {
            _logger.Info($"Hello, I am {nameof(ActivityA)}.");
        }
    }
}
```

Activity B:

```
using log4net;

namespace Container.Activities
{
    public class ActivityB : IActivity
    {
        private readonly ILog _logger;

        public ActivityB(ILog logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void Execute()
        {
            _logger.Info($"Hello, I am {nameof(ActivityB)}.");
        }
    }
}
```

Next to multiple IActivity instances, I have an IActivityExecutor interface.

```
namespace Container.Activities
{
    public interface IActivityExecutor
    {
        void Execute();
    }
}
```

The Activity Executor instance should execute all registered IActivity instances. Next it has its own ILog instance injected so it can write to the log file as well.

```
using log4net;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Container.Activities
{
    public class ActivityExecutor : IActivityExecutor
    {
        private readonly ILog _logger;
        private readonly IEnumerable<IActivity> _activities;

        public ActivityExecutor(ILog logger, IEnumerable<IActivity> activities)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _activities = activities;
        }

        public void Execute()
        {
            _logger.Info($"About to process {_activities.Count()}.");

            foreach (var activity in _activities)
            {
                activity.Execute();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output in my log file becomes as shown below. Note both ActivityA and ActivityB end up in the log file with logger name ActivityExecutor.

```
2019-03-19 14:43 [Test application] [1] INFO - Application started.
2019-03-19 14:43 [Container.Activities.ActivityExecutor] [1] INFO - About to process 2.
2019-03-19 14:43 [Container.Activities.ActivityExecutor] [1] INFO - Hello, I am ActivityA.
2019-03-19 14:43 [Container.Activities.ActivityExecutor] [1] INFO - Hello, I am ActivityB.
2019-03-19 14:43 [Test application] [1] INFO - Application stopped.
```

This output is not what I expect. I would expect to see the below log instead. So each activity logs using its own name.

```
2019-03-19 14:43 [Test application] [1] INFO - Application started.
2019-03-19 14:43 [Container.Activities.ActivityExecutor] [1] INFO - About to process 2.
2019-03-19 14:43 [Container.Activities.ActivityA] [1] INFO - Hello, I am ActivityA.
2019-03-19 14:43 [Container.Activities.ActivityB] [1] INFO - Hello, I am ActivityB.
2019-03-19 14:43 [Test application] [1] INFO - Application stopped.
```

The root cause for this issue seems to be related to the use of named registrations in my Unity container. If I add another interface parameter to the constructor of the ActivityExecutor and put that before the ILog parameter, the name of that component is used in the log file.

I can remove the ILog from all constructors in this program, and instead call the LogManager to get a logger with the name of each component. However, I prefer to inject the ILog interface when needed and use the Unity.log4net package.

```
_logger = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

Am I missing something here?